# Laravel Feature Testing change the database connection and database run time

Tags: laravel, unit-testing

I am testing my application setting `sqlite` as database. But for some tests i need `postgresql` connection. The reason is that `sqlite` doesnot support some `postgresql` features so for that particular test i am trying to change connection as `pgsql` and database name as `somedb`.

```
public function test_fetch_all_posts()
{

    $data = (object) [
        "id" => 126,
        "title" => "a",
        "description" => "Its a description",
        "target_price" => 3000,
        "label_id" => [1, 2],
        "additional_details" => "additonal details",
        "latitude" => "-31.953030",
        "longitude" => "115.853600",
    ];

    $this->postCreateService->create(data: $data, customerId: 1);

    $response = $this->getJson('/api/store/posts?storeId=1');

    $response->assertStatus(200);
}
```

Generally we use `sqlite` as memory database for faster testing. what does generally laravel developer take approach when some feature are not supported by `sqlite` for your default database (mysql or postgresql).

Answer (score 0):

There is two ways can work around, in your case, suggest testing with a mocked class.

To be more precise, you are trying to use a database different from the production environment, which means that even if you test the database, it is meaningless, because it is different from the database you will use in the production.

**1. Mocking the database parts.**

Use the Mockery interface to mocking all database parts.

Here is an untested example：

```php
public function test_fetch_all_posts(): void
{
    $this->instance(
        CreateService::class,
        Mockery::mock(CreateService::class, function (MockInterface $mock) {
            $mock->shouldReceive('create')->once();
        })
    );

    $data = (object) [
        "id" => 126,
        "title" => "a",
        "description" => "Its a description",
        "target_price" => 3000,
        "label_id" => [1, 2],
        "additional_details" => "additonal details",
        "latitude" => "-31.953030",
        "longitude" => "115.853600",
    ];

    $this->postCreateService->create(data: $data, customerId: 1);
}
```

Details about Mockery：

- [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/mocking#mocking-objects)
- [Mockery Docs](https://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/getting_started/quick_reference.html)

**2. Specify the testing environment.**

If you really want to use database with testing.

You can also create a `.env.testing` in project root, and assign a testing with specify driver for your unit test.

Laravel unit test will try to using `.env.testing` frist, if not exists then it will use `.env`.

```php
// In .env.testing
...
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=sinopac // You can set a testing database here.
DB_USERNAME=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=postgres
...
```

Details about `.env.testing`, see [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/testing#the-env-testing-environment-file).